# After latest update mouse crashes unity

Tags: mouse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xorg Segmentation Fault - seems to be relevant to evdev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101308/xorg-segmentation-fault-seems-to-be-relevant-to-evdev)

So moving the cursor crashes unity back to the login screen. This happens even when controlling the cursor with a keyboard.  Unity won't even start, unless in 2D. I've tried uninstalling ATI's drivers. No luck. This is some major suckage.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing Unity PPA.

```
    sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
    sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
    sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily
```