# Xorg Segmentation Fault - seems to be relevant to evdev

Tags: xorg, evdev

Since yesterday, after selecting to update some packages recommended by the update manager, I am not able to use my ubuntu 11.10.

Everything seems to be working fine, until I move the mouse.

As soon as the mouse is moved, xserver crashes with segmentation fault (Caught signal 11).

Here is the Xorg.0.log file -- any help on this will be **really** appreciated.

```
[    25.145] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    25.145] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    25.145] (++) using VT number 7

[    25.145] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    25.145] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    25.145] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    25.145] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    25.146] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    25.146] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    25.146] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    25.146] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.146]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    25.146]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    25.146] (==) RADEON(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    25.146] (==) RADEON(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    25.146] (==) RADEON(0): RGB weight 888
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[    25.146] (--) RADEON(0): Chipset: "ATI Radeon X1200" (ChipID = 0x791e)
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): PCI card detected
[    25.146] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    25.146] drmOpenDevice: open result is 12, (OK)
[    25.146] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:01:05.0
[    25.146] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    25.146] drmOpenDevice: open result is 12, (OK)
[    25.146] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 12
[    25.146] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:01:05.0
[    25.146] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[    25.146] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[    25.146] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[    25.146] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.146]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 2.5.0
[    25.146]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Color Tiling: enabled
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[    25.146] (II) RADEON(0): SwapBuffers wait for vsync: enabled
[    25.199] (II) RADEON(0): Output VGA-0 has no monitor section
[    25.372] (II) RADEON(0): Output S-video has no monitor section
[    25.404] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-0 has no monitor section
[    25.437] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-1 has no monitor section
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output VGA-0
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer: GSM  Model: 57a0  Serial#: 252027
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Year: 2011  Week: 10
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Sync:  Separate  Composite
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 48  vert.: 27
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): redX: 0.645 redY: 0.335   greenX: 0.301 greenY: 0.616
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): blueX: 0.145 blueY: 0.069   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Supported established timings:
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 720x400@70Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@60Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 640x480@75Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@60Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 800x600@75Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Supported standard timings:
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): #0: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 75  vid: 36737
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): #3: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  477 x 268 mm
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 155 MHz
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Monitor name: W2240
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Serial No: 110NDCR7E027
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): EDID (in hex):
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    00ffffffffffff001e6da0577bd80300
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    0a1501036c301b78ea3335a5554d9d25
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    115054a54b00b3008180818f714f0101
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    010101010101023a801871382d40582c
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    4500dd0c1100001a000000fd00384b1e
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    530f000a202020202020000000fc0057
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    323234300a20202020202020000000ff
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0):    003131304e44435237453032370a00e3
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 22432
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for horizontal sync
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Using EDID range info for vertical refresh
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-0
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync -vsync (67.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[    25.490] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz)
[    25.664] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output S-video
[    25.696] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DVI-0
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output DVI-1
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): Output VGA-0 connected
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): Output S-video disconnected
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-0 disconnected
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): Output DVI-1 disconnected
[    25.728] (II) RADEON(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Output VGA-0 using initial mode 1920x1080
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): mem size init: gart size :1fdff000 vram size: s:10000000 visible:f7d7000
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): EXA: Driver will allow EXA pixmaps in VRAM
[    25.729] (**) RADEON(0): Display dimensions: (480, 270) mm
[    25.729] (**) RADEON(0): DPI set to (101, 101)
[    25.729] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    25.729] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    25.729] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    25.729] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.729]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    25.729]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    25.729] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    25.729] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    25.729] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    25.729] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    25.729] (II) Unloading vesa
[    25.729] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    25.729] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    25.729] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    25.729] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    25.729] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: r300
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Front buffer size: 8160K
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 221065K
[    25.729] (==) RADEON(0): Backing store disabled
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Direct rendering enabled
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Render acceleration enabled for R300/R400/R500 type cards.
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Setting EXA maxPitchBytes
[    25.729] (II) EXA(0): Driver allocated offscreen pixmaps
[    25.729] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[    25.729] (II)         Solid
[    25.729] (II)         Copy
[    25.729] (II)         Composite (RENDER acceleration)
[    25.729] (II)         UploadToScreen
[    25.729] (II)         DownloadFromScreen
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Acceleration enabled
[    25.729] (==) RADEON(0): DPMS enabled
[    25.729] (==) RADEON(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): Set up textured video
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): [XvMC] Associated with Radeon Textured Video.
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): [XvMC] Extension initialized.
[    25.729] (II) RADEON(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    25.736] (--) RandR disabled
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    25.736] (II) Initializing built-in extension GESTURE
[    25.741] (II) AIGLX: Trying DRI driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r300_dri.so
[    25.750] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    25.750] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    25.750] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[    25.750] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
[    25.750] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    25.751] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized r300
[    25.751] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    25.751] (II) RADEON(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[    25.766] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    25.773] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    25.773] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    25.773] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    25.773] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.773] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    25.773]    compiled for 1.10.2, module version = 2.6.0
[    25.773]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    25.773]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 12.3
[    25.774] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    25.774] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.774] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    25.774] (**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    25.774] (--) Power Button: Found keys
[    25.774] (II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    25.774] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    25.774] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    25.774] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    25.774] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    25.774] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,gr"
[    25.774] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    25.774] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    25.775] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-9078D1F245FADE3CB4AD835262E1036C04792E56.xkm
[    25.777] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    25.777] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    25.777] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    25.777] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.777] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    25.777] (**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    25.777] (--) Power Button: Found keys
[    25.777] (II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    25.777] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    25.777] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    25.777] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    25.777] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    25.777] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,gr"
[    25.777] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    25.777] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    25.780] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00 (/dev/input/event2)
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    25.780] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00'
[    25.780] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: always reports core events
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    25.780] (--) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Found 9 mouse buttons
[    25.780] (--) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    25.780] (--) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Found relative axes
[    25.780] (--) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Found x and y relative axes
[    25.780] (II) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Configuring as mouse
[    25.780] (II) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Adding scrollwheel support
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    25.780] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input2/event2"
[    25.780] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00" (type: MOUSE)
[    25.780] (II) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: initialized for relative axes.
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    25.780] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    25.781] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    25.781] (**) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    25.781] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    25.781] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    25.782] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    25.782] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    25.782] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard'
[    25.782] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.782] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[    25.782] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    25.782] (--) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[    25.782] (II) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    25.782] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-8/1-8.1/1-8.1:1.0/input/input3/event3"
[    25.782] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    25.782] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    25.782] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    25.782] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,gr"
[    25.782] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    25.782] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    25.783] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    25.783] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    25.783] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard'
[    25.783] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    25.783] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[    25.783] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    25.783] (--) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Found 1 mouse buttons
[    25.783] (--) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[    25.783] (II) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[    25.783] (II) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    25.783] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    25.783] (**) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    25.783] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-8/1-8.1/1-8.1:1.1/input/input4/event4"
[    25.783] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    25.783] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    25.783] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    25.783] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,gr"
[    25.783] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    25.783] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    25.784] 
Backtrace:
[    25.784] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x26) [0x460566]
[    25.784] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x64b7a) [0x464b7a]
[    25.784] 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f5cf5be3000+0x10060) [0x7f5cf5bf3060]
[    25.784] 3: /usr/bin/X (_miPointerSetPosition+0x121) [0x45d671]
[    25.784] 4: /usr/bin/X (GetPointerEvents+0x3ea) [0x44488a]
[    25.784] 5: /usr/bin/X (xf86PostMotionEventM+0x73) [0x4805b3]
[    25.784] 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f5cef1a3000+0x5f23) [0x7f5cef1a8f23]
[    25.784] 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f5cef1a3000+0x65fb) [0x7f5cef1a95fb]
[    25.784] 8: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x6da77) [0x46da77]
[    25.784] 9: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x1229ee) [0x5229ee]
[    25.784] 10: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f5cf5be3000+0x10060) [0x7f5cf5bf3060]
[    25.784] 11: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__open64+0x10) [0x7f5cf4bd1840]
[    25.784] 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (_IO_file_fopen+0xd9) [0x7f5cf4b72389]
[    25.784] 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f5cf4afe000+0x69166) [0x7f5cf4b67166]
[    25.784] 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 (0x7f5cf648b000+0x5c0b) [0x7f5cf6490c0b]
[    25.784] 15: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 (udev_device_get_devnode+0x31) [0x7f5cf649171c]
[    25.784] 16: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x1238e9) [0x5238e9]
[    25.784] 17: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x12432e) [0x52432e]
[    25.784] 18: /usr/bin/X (config_init+0x9) [0x5235d9]
[    25.784] 19: /usr/bin/X (InitInput+0xf5) [0x472655]
[    25.784] 20: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x232c6) [0x4232c6]
[    25.784] 21: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f5cf4b1f30d]
[    25.784] 22: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x235ed) [0x4235ed]
[    25.784] Segmentation fault at address 0x7fff00000780
[    25.784] 
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[    25.784] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    25.784] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    25.784] 
[    25.784] (II) Power Button: Close
[    25.784] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    25.784] (II) Unloading evdev
[    25.784] (II) Power Button: Close
[    25.784] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    25.784] (II) Unloading evdev
[    25.785] (II) Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00: Close
[    25.785] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    25.785] (II) Unloading evdev
[    25.785] (II) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Close
[    25.785] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    25.785] (II) Unloading evdev
[    25.785] (II) Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard: Close
[    25.785] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    25.785] (II) Unloading evdev
[    25.785] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[    25.802]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo aptitude install libxfixes3=1:5.0-4
sudo aptitude install xserver-xephyr=2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2
sudo aptitude install unity=4.28.0-0ubuntu2
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-core=2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.1
```

and downgrading some packages from previous answers did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the offending package on my system is `xserver-xorg-core` version `2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2newyork1`.

Downgrading it with

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core=2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4
```

saved the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Downgrading xorg, xserver-xorg, xserver-xorg-core, xserver-xorg-input-all, xserver-xorg-video-all from version 7.6+7ubuntu7.1 to 7.6+7ubuntu7 seems like a workaround for me.

Comment: Didn't work or me.. too bad I've already started reinstalling the OS. Also, I consider downgrading to 10.04..

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded xorg-common, xserver-xorg-core, xserver-xephyr and libxfixes3, than all unity packages from daily to stable versions and it works.